# How to put MutableList<> into Entity (room, Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I found some difficulties adding a custom list into an entity. This is my code and I'm not so sure what I am missing

AppUsageData

```
class AppUsageData(val appName: String, val packageName: String, val imageId: Drawable, val maxUsage: Int, val mAhPerHour: Float, val mAhDrained: Float, val allMahDrained: Float, val allSecondsOfUsage: Int, val firstTimeStamp: Long, val lastTimeStamp: Long, val totalTimeVisible: Long, val lastTimeUsed: Long, val lastTimeVisible: Long, val totalTimeInForeground: Long, val lastTimeForegroundServiceUsed: Long, val totalTimeForegroundServiceUsed: Long)
```

Converters

```
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromAppUsageDataList(value : MutableList<AppUsageData>) = Json.encodeToString(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun toAppUsageDataList(value: String) = Json.decodeFromString<MutableList<AppUsageData>>(value)
}
```

Database

```
@Database(entities = [..., ...],
    autoMigrations = [
    AutoMigration (from = 3, to = 4)],
    version = 4,
    exportSchema = true)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class BatteryInfoDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
.
.
.
}
```

And this is an exception I got

```
Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'AppUsageData' is not found.
    Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.Platform_commonKt.serializerNotRegistered(Platform.common.kt:91)
        at kotlinx.serialization.internal.PlatformKt.platformSpecificSerializerNotRegistered(Platform.kt:29)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:59)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source:1)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.builtinSerializerOrNull$SerializersKt__SerializersKt(Serializers.kt:79)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializerByKTypeImpl$SerializersKt__SerializersKt(Serializers.kt:69)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt__SerializersKt.serializer(Serializers.kt:54)
        at kotlinx.serialization.SerializersKt.serializer(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.paget96.batteryguru.utils.database.batteryinfo.Converters.fromAppUsageDataList(Converters.kt:17)
```

I have tried adding the @Serializable to the *class AppUsageData*, but same thing occurs

Comment: Have you done what the error told you to do?

Comment: Yes, tried to add @Serializable to it, again, nothing

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question to include that? You definitely need the annotation for this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just missed this plugin, after adding this and brought back @Serializable to *class AppUsageData* everything works.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.5.0'
}
```